# Objects in JavaScript using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

It does not show me data from the object..

HTML:

```
<div class="form-data">
    <select name="option">
        <option value="0"></option>
        <option value="1">Name</option>
        <option value="2">Lastname</option>
        <option value="3">Age</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div id="output"></div>
```

This is SELECT in HTML

JS:

```
var obj = {
        name: "Alex",
        lastname: "Strukov",
        age: "21"
    }

    $("select[name='option']").on("change", function() {
        var value = $("select[name='option']").val();
        switch (value) {
            case 1:
            $("div#output").text(obj["name"]);
            break;

            case 2:
            $("#output").text(obj["lastname"]);
            break;

            case 3:
            $("#output").text(obj["age"]);
            break;
        }
    });
```

[image]

For example: I want to select "Name", and let the object display the data

Comment: Hi! Show us your HTML code from your `<select>` to help us ;)

Comment: What are the values in the select? Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The code looks OK! Something must probably be wrong in the HTML then

Comment: The `value` of an `input` or `select` is always a string. `switch` uses `===`-style comparisons, so your cases will never match, as they're numbers, not strings. Either make them strings, or parse the value.

Comment: `val()` returns a string, so it needs to be `case "1":` etc

Comment: Side note: In your handler, no need to re-query the DOM, just use `var value = $(this).val();`

Comment: Thanks to everyone, now everything works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add onchange handler to the select & Pass the value of the selected function.
In your case the object does not have a key by name 1,2,3. So `$("select[name='option']").val();` will not able to retrieve any value by key from the object

```js
var obj = {
  name: "Alex",
  lastname: "Strukov",
  age: "21"
}

function showValue(val) {
  $("#output").text(obj[val]);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select onchange="showValue(this.value)">
<option value ="name">Name</option>
<option value ="lastname">lastname</option>
<option value ="age">age</option>
</select>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Works! Thank you